# Get hardware information in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, motherboard, hardware-id, sn

Can anyone provide me a piece of code in dart language to get motherboard Serial Number?
I found some code in c# but I can't write it in dart language .

Comment: For which platform you are looking? like PC or Mobile

Comment: for pc platform

Answer (score 0):

You can get some info with [Device Info Plus](https://pub.dev/packages/device_info_plus/example) package, even related to some internals, although I doubt if motherboard serial number - this information is so low level, that I find it hard to find any use case different than pure curiosity. But there are some properties returned for windows/linux platform which you have to check yourself.

In case you have windows, look [how the plugin is written internally](https://github.com/fluttercommunity/plus_plugins/blob/main/packages/device_info_plus/device_info_plus/lib/src/device_info_plus_windows.dart) - there's a clue. You can fork the plugin and add new property based on some registry key for motherboards serial number. [I'd start looking here](https://technical-tips.com/blog/hardware/motherboardserial-number-registry-find-1811). For linux there's similar way of finding things out.